# NetworkOnMainThreadException Firebase Crash

Tags: android, firebase, networkonmainthread, firebase-crash-reporting

In my Firebase Crash Reporting, I'm getting an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. The issue is it's saying it's from a method that I do not recognize. "MainActivity.a()"

```
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork (StrictMode.java:1145)
java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName (InetAddress.java:385)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl (InetAddress.java:236)
java.net.InetAddress.getByName (InetAddress.java:289)
--> com.mycompany.h.h ()
--> com.mycompany.h.b ()
--> com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.a ()
--> com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.a ()
--> com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity$127.onClick ()
android.support.v7.app.d$b.handleMessage ()
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5102)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:785)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:601)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

The ones I've marked with an arrow, I have no idea where to trace them to because those methods don't exist in my code.

As another added bonus, I'm only getting this crash on API 19. I test on API 23 and I'm also targeting on 23.

My app sends and receives OSC info, so trying to track down which individual method could have accidentally sent something on the MainThread is challenging, although, the only way I send OSC commands is via AsyncTask, so I'm unsure what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confusing your app that case your log can't distingush this method , if you had push your app to AppStore , you can try to decompile your app and find where this method is or you can cancel confusion and try to reproduce this problem , this is my viewpoint , hope it helps you.

Comment: Sounds indeed like the cause. See the documentation on how to upload the proguard mapping file to Firebase so that it automatically shows the original stack trace: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#deobfuscate_proguard_labels